# Place ul li items according to time

Tags: javascript, html

I have a simple task app where you add a time that you want to start the task and a task. The app lists the items according to the order they are entered. 
I was wondering if there was a way that the list items would be listed according to time, e.g. if I enter task "A" and set it for 8:00 am, then enter task "B" which is set for 7:00am, I would like task "B" to be listed above task "A".

```js
// Create a "close" button and append it to each list item
var myNodelist = document.getElementsByTagName("LI");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < myNodelist.length; i++) {
 var span = document.createElement("SPAN");
 var txt = document.createTextNode("\u00D7");
 span.className = "close";
 span.appendChild(txt);
 myNodelist[i].appendChild(span);
}

// Click on a close button to hide the current list item
var close = document.getElementsByClassName("close");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < close.length; i++) {
 close[i].onclick = function () {
  var div = this.parentElement;
  div.style.display = "none";
 }
}

// Add a "checked" symbol when clicking on a list item
var list = document.querySelector('ul');
list.addEventListener('click', function (ev) {
 if (ev.target.tagName === 'LI') {
  ev.target.classList.toggle('checked');
 }
}, false);

// Create a new list item when clicking on the "Add" button
function newElement() {
 var li = document.createElement("li");

 li.className = "column";
 li.draggable = "true"

 var inputValue = document.getElementById("myInput").value;

 var inputValue1 = document.getElementById("myInput1").value;


 var t = document.createTextNode(inputValue);
 li.appendChild(t);

 var tt = document.createTextNode(inputValue1);
 li.appendChild(tt);

 if (inputValue === '') {
  alert("You must write task!");
 } else {

  document.getElementById("columns").appendChild(li);

 }
 document.getElementById("myInput").value = "";
 document.getElementById("myInput1").value = "";

 var span = document.createElement("SPAN");
 var txt = document.createTextNode("\u00D7");
 span.className = "close";
 span.appendChild(txt);
 li.appendChild(span);

 for (i = 0; i < close.length; i++) {
  close[i].onclick = function () {
   var div = this.parentElement;
   div.style.display = "none";
  }
 }
}
var input = document.getElementById("myInput");

// Execute a function when the user releases a key on the keyboard
input.addEventListener("keyup", function (event) {
 // Number 13 is the "Enter" key on the keyboard
 if (event.keyCode === 13) {
  // Cancel the default action, if needed
  event.preventDefault();
  // Trigger the button element with a click
  document.getElementById("myBtn").click();
 }
});
```

```css
#myInput1 {
 width: 130px;
 height: 36px;
 margin-right: 10px;
 /* margin-left: -40px; */
 /* padding: 10px; */
 /* color: red; */
 /* box-sizing: border-box; */
 /* background-color: blue; */
 /* display: inline-block; */
}

[draggable] {
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  /* Required to make elements draggable in old WebKit */
  -khtml-user-drag: element;
  -webkit-user-drag: element;
}

/* Include the padding and border in an element's total width and height */
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;

}

/* Remove margins and padding from the list */
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

/* Style the list items */
ul li {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  padding: 12px 8px 12px 40px;
  background: #DCEDC2;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.2s;
  color: rgb(94, 91, 91);

  /* make the list items unselectable */
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

/* Set all odd list items to a different color (zebra-stripes) */
ul li:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #FFD3B5;
}

/* Darker background-color on hover */
ul li:hover {
  background: #A8E6CE;
}

/* When clicked on, add a background color and strike out text */
ul li.checked {
  background: #888;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: line-through;
}

/* Add a "checked" mark when clicked on */
ul li.checked::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  border-color: #fff;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 2px 2px 0;
  top: 10px;
  left: 16px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  height: 15px;
  width: 7px;
}

/* Style the close button */
.close {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  padding: 12px 16px 12px 16px;
}

.close:hover {
  background-color: #ff8c94;
  color: white;
}

/* Style the header */
.header {
  background-color: #ff8c94;
  padding: 30px 40px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Clear floats after the header */
.header:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

/* Style the input */
input {
  margin: 0;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  width: 75%;
  padding: 10px;
  float: left;
  font-size: 16px;
 }
```

```html
 <div id="myDIV" class="header">
  <h2>My Daily Tasks</h2>
  <p>Add a time and task then press enter</p>
  <input type="time" id="myInput1">
  <input name="text" type="text" id="myInput" placeholder="My task...">

  <span onclick="newElement()" class="addBtn" id="myBtn"></span>
 </div>
 <ul id="columns">

 </ul>
```

Comment: The submitted tasks do not appear to be listed on screen on submit, nor does the error message if the task name is empty. Has this functionality been implemented successfully yet?

Comment: u r code is not properly working,,

Comment: Sorry, fixed it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly added time to `li` element as `date-time` attribute

```
li.setAttribute("data-time", document.getElementById("myInput1").value);
```

After that create an array from `li` elements using `date-time` attributes

Sorted array based on `date-time` attributes and append `li` elements from array to parent `ul`.

```
document.getElementById("columns").appendChild(li);
  setTimeout(function(){
  var sortItems = document.querySelectorAll("[data-time]");
  var elemArray = Array.from(sortItems);
  elemArray.sort(function(a, b){
  if(a.getAttribute('data-time') < b.getAttribute('data-time')){return -1}else{return 1}
  });
  document.getElementById("columns").innerHTML = "";

  elemArray.forEach(appendFunction);


  function appendFunction(item, index) {
  document.getElementById("columns").innerHTML += item.outerHTML; 
  }
  }, 200);
```

```js
// Create a "close" button and append it to each list item
var myNodelist = document.getElementsByTagName("LI");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < myNodelist.length; i++) {
 var span = document.createElement("SPAN");
 var txt = document.createTextNode("\u00D7");
 span.className = "close";
 span.appendChild(txt);
 myNodelist[i].appendChild(span);
}

// Click on a close button to hide the current list item
var close = document.getElementsByClassName("close");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < close.length; i++) {
 close[i].onclick = function () {
  var div = this.parentElement;
  div.style.display = "none";
 }
}

// Add a "checked" symbol when clicking on a list item
var list = document.querySelector('ul');
list.addEventListener('click', function (ev) {
 if (ev.target.tagName === 'LI') {
  ev.target.classList.toggle('checked');
 }
}, false);

var arr = [];

// Create a new list item when clicking on the "Add" button
function newElement() {
 var li = document.createElement("li");

 li.className = "column";
 li.draggable = "true";
 li.setAttribute("data-time", document.getElementById("myInput1").value);

 var inputValue = document.getElementById("myInput").value;

 var inputValue1 = document.getElementById("myInput1").value;
 

 var t = document.createTextNode(inputValue);
 li.appendChild(t);

 var tt = document.createTextNode(inputValue1);
 li.appendChild(tt);

 if (inputValue === '') {
  alert("You must write task!");
 } else {

  document.getElementById("columns").appendChild(li);
  setTimeout(function(){
  var sortItems = document.querySelectorAll("[data-time]");
  var elemArray = Array.from(sortItems);
  elemArray.sort(function(a, b){
  if(a.getAttribute('data-time') < b.getAttribute('data-time')){return -1}else{return 1}
  });
  document.getElementById("columns").innerHTML = "";
  
  elemArray.forEach(appendFunction);
  
  
  function appendFunction(item, index) {
  document.getElementById("columns").innerHTML += item.outerHTML; 
  }
  }, 200);
  
  

 }
 document.getElementById("myInput").value = "";
 document.getElementById("myInput1").value = "";

 var span = document.createElement("SPAN");
 var txt = document.createTextNode("\u00D7");
 span.className = "close";
 span.appendChild(txt);
 li.appendChild(span);

 for (i = 0; i < close.length; i++) {
  close[i].onclick = function () {
   var div = this.parentElement;
   div.style.display = "none";
  }
 }
}
var input = document.getElementById("myInput");

// Execute a function when the user releases a key on the keyboard
input.addEventListener("keyup", function (event) {
 // Number 13 is the "Enter" key on the keyboard
 if (event.keyCode === 13) {
  // Cancel the default action, if needed
  event.preventDefault();
  // Trigger the button element with a click
  document.getElementById("myBtn").click();
 }
});
```

```css
#myInput1 {
 width: 130px;
 height: 36px;
 margin-right: 10px;
 /* margin-left: -40px; */
 /* padding: 10px; */
 /* color: red; */
 /* box-sizing: border-box; */
 /* background-color: blue; */
 /* display: inline-block; */
}

[draggable] {
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  /* Required to make elements draggable in old WebKit */
  -khtml-user-drag: element;
  -webkit-user-drag: element;
}

/* Include the padding and border in an element's total width and height */
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;

}

/* Remove margins and padding from the list */
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

/* Style the list items */
ul li {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  padding: 12px 8px 12px 40px;
  background: #DCEDC2;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.2s;
  color: rgb(94, 91, 91);

  /* make the list items unselectable */
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

/* Set all odd list items to a different color (zebra-stripes) */
ul li:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #FFD3B5;
}

/* Darker background-color on hover */
ul li:hover {
  background: #A8E6CE;
}

/* When clicked on, add a background color and strike out text */
ul li.checked {
  background: #888;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: line-through;
}

/* Add a "checked" mark when clicked on */
ul li.checked::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  border-color: #fff;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 2px 2px 0;
  top: 10px;
  left: 16px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  height: 15px;
  width: 7px;
}

/* Style the close button */
.close {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  padding: 12px 16px 12px 16px;
}

.close:hover {
  background-color: #ff8c94;
  color: white;
}

/* Style the header */
.header {
  background-color: #ff8c94;
  padding: 30px 40px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Clear floats after the header */
.header:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

/* Style the input */
input {
  margin: 0;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  width: 75%;
  padding: 10px;
  float: left;
  font-size: 16px;
 }
```

```html
<div id="myDIV" class="header">
  <h2>My Daily Tasks</h2>
  <p>Add a time and task then press enter</p>
  <input type="time" id="myInput1">
  <input name="text" type="text" id="myInput" placeholder="My task...">

  <span onclick="newElement()" class="addBtn" id="myBtn"></span>
 </div>
 <ul id="columns">

 </ul>
```

Comment: A good answer should have a description of how it has solved the problem. There is a lot of code to sift through there to spot the changes.

Comment: I updated the answer added description, sory for my bad english :) 
it doesn't matter @HesamAlavi

Comment: @ariferol01 your code worked for arranging the list items according to time, but now a part of my code does not work anymore:  // Click on a close button to hide the current list item
var close = document.getElementsByClassName("close");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < close.length; i++) {
 close[i].onclick = function () {
  var div = this.parentElement;
  div.style.display = "none";
 }
}

Answer (score 1):

Store the time as a data attribute, and use `Node.insertBefore()` to add the new list element in the right place, chronologically:

```js
let newTask = {
    time: 1200,
    task: "Run errands"
};

let todo = document.getElementById("todo");
[...todo.children].forEach(el => {
    if(newTask.time < parseInt(el.dataset.time, 10)){
        let li = document.createElement("li")
        li.dataset.time = newTask.time
        li.innerHTML = newTask.task
        todo.insertBefore(li, el)
    }
})
```

```html
<ul id="todo">
    <li data-time="0730">Wake up</li>
    <li data-time="2000">Sleep</li>
</ul>
```